# Extract refresh token value

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I wonder how can I extrat refresh token value using Spring Boot and Spring Security OAuth2?

There are plans for [implementing Refresh Token Repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4371) but for now is there any easy way to intercept this value?

Clarification:
This is client application. I'm using 3rd party resource server, Spring Boot 2.x, Spring Security 5.x and Spring Security OAuth2 2.3.x

Comment: You get the refresh token with [`DefaultOAuth2AccessToken.html#getRefreshToken`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/common/DefaultOAuth2AccessToken.html#getRefreshToken()).

Comment: @dur any Idea how do I get access to this object? The closest thing is [OAuth2AccessToken](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/OAuth2AccessToken.html) I get from [OAuth2AuthorizedClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2AuthorizedClient.html)

Comment: Do you use Spring Security 5?

Comment: @dur yes, basically everything is from RELEASE tag

Comment: Ok, then it seems, that you have to use `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`.

Comment: @dur and any idea what to do with it?